# Why am I getting and error when I add in without to my promql query?

Tags: average, promql

Trying to set up a dashboard to keep an eye on my hardware. I am running into issue with the without(cpu) causing an error.

```
avg without(cpu) irate(node_cpu_seconds_total {instance="nodeexp:9100", job="nodeexp", mode!="idle"} [1m])
```

The error I get with this query is error:"1:18: parse error: unexpected identifier "irate" in aggregation"

I have also tried it this way.

```
avg(without(cpu) irate(node_cpu_seconds_total {instance="nodeexp:9100", job="nodeexp", mode!="idle"} [1m]))
```

The error I get with this query is error:"1:12: parse error: unexpected "(" in aggregation"

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.

```
avg without(cpu) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="nodeexp:9100", job="nodeexp", mode!="idle"}[1m]))
```